# Is there a way to get track IDs of the tracks in a Spotify playlist using the Spotify JAVA API?

Tags: java, wrapper, spotify

I've been using the Java wrapper for the Spotify API. I have been successful in retrieving the required playlist but I'm not able to get the track IDs of the tracks in the playlist.

Here is the code I'm using to get the playlist items.

```
playlistID = "37i9dQZF1DWXLeA8Omikj7";


        getPlaylistsItemsRequest = spotifyApi.getPlaylistsItems(playlistID).build();



        Paging<PlaylistTrack> playlistTrackPaging = getPlaylistsItems_Sync();
        PlaylistTrack[] items = playlistTrackPaging.getItems();

        System.out.println(items.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(items[i].getTrack().toString());
        }
```

The above code gives output in this format:

```
com.wrapper.spotify.model_objects.specification.Track@6c40365c
```

The alphanumeric in the end unfortunately isn't the track ID.

The PlaylistTrack object doesn't seem to have any way to get the track ID. Anyone know how I can get the track IDs?
Been struggling with this for a while now. Thanks!

Comment: Please always specify the version of a library so that people can help you easily :)

Comment: Also, see [CONTRIBUTING.md#your-questions](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#your-questions), and tag your questions regarding this API wrapper on this StackOverflow with `spotify-web-api-java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes

Of course that's possible! :)

Since [`v6.0.0-RC1`](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java/releases/tag/6.0.0-RC1) of [spotify-web-api-java](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java/) the [PlaylistTrack](http://michaelthelin.se/spotify-web-api-java/com/wrapper/spotify/model_objects/specification/PlaylistTrack.html)s, which are returned by your request, now contain an [IPlaylistItem](http://michaelthelin.se/spotify-web-api-java/com/wrapper/spotify/model_objects/IPlaylistItem.html) instead of a simple [Track](http://michaelthelin.se/spotify-web-api-java/com/wrapper/spotify/model_objects/specification/Track.html) due to changes related to [the new podcasts API](https://developer.spotify.com/community/news/2020/03/20/introducing-podcasts-api/), which made endpoint return types depend on the request's context.

The current solution is to cast the items to their expected type. In your example, the `println` within the `for`-loop should look like this:

```
System.out.println(((Track) items[i].getTrack()).getId());
```

Depending on incoming pull requests, this could be improved in the future though: see [the discussion in issue #201](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java/issues/201).